# How to check the rows of ng-repeat values in angular js

Tags: angularjs, jsp

How to access the rows of ng-repeat of array of arrays?
in jsp:
I have one json array object which have content of table.
and another array object table header.

so below I used to implement it. But I have one situation that if col1 data is Y then I need to display one check box. How to check that..

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<div class="table-container">
<table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th lr-drag-src="headers" lr-drop-target="headers" ng-repeat="col in columns" st-sort="{{col}}">{{col}}</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>
<input st-search="firstName" placeholder="search for firstname" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
</th>
<th colspan="4">
<input st-search placeholder="global search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
<td ng-repeat="col in columns**>{{row[col]}}</**td>
</tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="isLoading" class="loading-indicator"></div>
    </body>
```

Single array:
    
    
    ')" id = "checkExport" value = "{{result.TX_ID}}">
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    {{result.TX_ID}}
                                                    {{result.value2}}

Comment: {{row[col]}}  -- how to check condition while ng-repeat to check if value is Y for one col then display as check box. how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowCollection[1].columns with foreach to find if some value in columns contains Y. But the better way just use ng-show="col === Y" as attribute to your checkbox. Or ng-hide if you need to hide it.

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks for your fast reply. What I need is one of the element in json array is Y or empty, If its Y then display check box, if empty display none. in json array [{col1:aaa, col2:bbb, col3:ccc,col4:Y}] if col4 is Y then I need to display as check box, this above scenario I have done using single ng-repeat, but when Itried using mulitiple ng-repeat I unable to access the elements which I using as {{row[col]}}

Comment: I have also above code with single array which is working but I need multiple array I not sure please advice

Comment: <td ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col}}
<input type="checkbox" ng-show="col === Y">
</td>

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by multiple array, just use ng-repeat.